# How to make hold attacking nobody

Tags: dota-2

I do not like the way DotA2 has implemented the hold function.

I would like to have **stop** as a button to cancel attacks and spells but keep autoattacking activated.

On the other hand i would like **hold** as a button to cancel attacks and spells and disable autoattacking (not even autoattacking while in range).

So i want to combine both states of "Auto Attack", switching live while playing.

[image]

The reasoning behind this is the fact that i need to spam a key to not attack with a ranged hero.

Basically this would be the behavior Heroes of Newerth implemented.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: no. Hold cancels commands but your hero will attack if anything comes in range. if you are melee this behavior is insignificant but as a ranged hero you need to spam your stop command to not attack. for example if you are waiting in a jukespot to leech xp you do not want to autoattack a nearby creep to give away your position.

Comment: then i quite don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @WizLiz i am going to make a video for you then

Comment: @WizLiz i added the video. hope it becomes more clear now.

Comment: I'm confused here- what's the problem with playing with autoattack off and just using A+left click when you'd like to attack without targeting?

Comment: it is not optimal. if you summon creeps they wont autoattack then. furthermore i am used to spamming s in dota1 is that possible with autoatk off? i dont think so

Comment: @Wandang I actually don't think that's true. Even with auto-attack off there are situations when your hero/summons will attack without you explicitly telling them. For example, when pushing a lane your hero will automatically attack the next creep after the one you were previously attacking was killed. I'm also pretty sure that newly summoned units begin attacking immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just use this script:

```
alias "autoAtkOn_Stop" "dota_player_units_auto_attack 1;dota_stop"
alias "autoAtkOff_Hold" "dota_player_units_auto_attack 0;dota_hold"
bind "S" "autoAtkOn_Stop"
bind "D" "autoAtkOff_Hold"
```

Change `S` and `D` according to your needs.

This script does set the autoattack-setting from the settings menu to on when you press `S` and issues a stop command(canceling your spellcast,attack).

If you press `D` it will set the autoattack to off and issue a hold command(basically the same as before)

See this video for live demonstration:

Comment: Okay I get it now, pretty neat stuff